# Side derivatives equal

Tags: derivatives

The function

$f(x) = \sqrt{\cosh(x) - 1} $

is not differentiable at $x=0$ because the domain of differentiability is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.

But shouldn't the right derivative and left derivative (calculated with the limit, by definition) be different? Because I'm getting the exact same result ($0$) and I'm not understanding if this is possible or not.

Comment: Can you show us how you achieve the result $0$ ?

Comment: Hint: by Taylor, you function is essentially $|x|/\sqrt2$ near $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cosh(x)$ is an even function so is your $f(x)$, so the derivatives using the limit definition should have opposite signs. These limits are $\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2$, not $0$.

Comment: Yves.. That's right (I deleted my embarrassing anwer...) +1.